# Manage having experimental features inside our power apps that will be in production in 2 months

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-platform

I am working on a Power Apps inside a solution that is connected to SharePoint. now i need to use those 2 experimental features :-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1699785801430.png]

In short we need those features as otherwise our apps will miss important features.

1. We need the PDF Function. as we want to generate PDF files from power apps, where using the OneDrive connector can only allow generating files with max of 2 MB, while in our case the files can have their sizes up to 10++ MB.
2. We need the Enhanced component properties,  since we have around 70 delete buttons, and we do not want to have 70 separate popup components,,, so we need to build the popup at one place and called it from 70 different places.

so what we can face (worst case scenario ) if we adopt those experimental features? i mean what can be the worst case? let say both feature were removed or dramatically changed, then what we will need to do?,, will this cause our power app to break or just the related functionalities? only the related functions will break and we can replace them with other approaches ? am i correct? we are planning to go live with this power app in almost 2 months (late January 2024), and we will provide support for it for 6 months (mid July 2024)... Can anyone advice on the above case please?

Thanks